# JPA AttributeConverter not honored in a Spring-data/hibernate query when used in a composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, spring-data

This is my enum:

```
    public enum FooBarType {
        Foo,
        Bar;

        @javax.persistence.Converter
        public static class Converter implements AttributeConverter<FooBarType, String> {
            @Override
            public String convertToDatabaseColumn(FooBarType t) {
                return t.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public FooBarType convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
                for (FooBarType value : FooBarType.values()) {
                    if (value.name().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                        return value;
                    }
                }

                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for enum: " + s);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my Entity:

```
@Table
@IdClass(FooBar.PrimaryKey.class)
public class FooBar {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String id;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fooBarType")
    @Convert(converter = FooBarType.Converter.class)
    public FooBarType fooBarType;

    @Column(name = "value")
    public int value;

    public static class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
        public String id;
        public FooBarType fooBarType;
    }
}
```

And my repository:

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends Repository<FooBar, FooBar.PrimaryKey> {
    FooBar getByIdAndFooBarType(String id, FooBarType fooBarType);
}
```

This is the data in the database. I know the case of 'FOO' is wrong, but that's the part I'm trying to achieve: case-insensitive conversion.

```
+----------+--------------+---------+
| id       | fooBarType   | value   |
+----------+--------------+---------+
| user-1   |          FOO |     998 |
+----------+--------------+---------+
```

When I test the `getByIdAndFooBarType("someId", FooBarType.Foo)` method, this exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:418)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:418)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getByUserIdAndAppType(Unknown Source)
        at com.treeboxsolutions.services.onCredentialService.databaseProviders.dataAccessLayer.repositories.CurrentCredentialRepositoryTest.saveShouldCorrectlySave(CurrentCredentialRepositoryTest.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:524)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy50.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 43 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2557)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid value for getInt() - 'Foo'
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2705)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2793)
        at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$OrdinalEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:372)
        at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:641)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:785)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:721)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
        ... 74 more
```

It seems that the Spring-data/hibernate query builder isn't honoring the `@Convert` attribute.
If I put the `@Enumerated` attribute, the `@Convert` attribute is ignored, and an expected exception is thrown. The exception basically says that it cannot map 'FOO' back to FooBarType (due to case-sensitivity).

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown name value [FOO] for enum class [FooBarType]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [FOO] for enum class [FooBarType]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:418)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.getByCertificateUid(Unknown Source)
        at FooBarRepositoryTest.getByIdAndFooBarTypeShouldBeCorrect(CredentialRepositoryTest.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [FOO] for enum class [FooBarType]
        at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.fromName(EnumType.java:467)
        at org.hibernate.type.EnumType$NamedEnumValueMapper.getValue(EnumType.java:452)
        at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.nullSafeGet(EnumType.java:107)
        at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeGet(CustomType.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2969)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1696)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1628)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1515)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:726)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:953)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
        at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1300)
        at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:495)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:71)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:364)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 43 more
```

---

---

### Update! This issue only affect composite primary keys

Regular columns work as expected with the `@Converter` annotation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `Convert` and `Id` annotations on same field, nor `Convert` and `Enumerated`. Use `EmbeddedId` instead as seen by `@Converter` documentation:

> Note that Id attributes, version attributes, relationship attributes, and attributes explicitly annotated as Enumerated or Temporal (or designated as such via XML) will not be converted.

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Converter.html, JSR-338, Chapter 11.1.10 Convert annotation, page 438.

Comment: I think this is already pretty clear from the other answers. Do you know why you can't use `Convert` and `Id`, nor `Convert` and `Enumerated` annotations on the same field?

Comment: Added the excerpt from `@Converter`.

Comment: Also added source to JSR 338

Answer (score 2):

For a really odd reason, if I went the route of using `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId` of declaring the composite key (instead of using `@IdClass`), the @Convert annotation is honored.
It's a disconnect in behaviour, in my opinion.

Working code:

```
public enum FooBarType {
    Foo,
    Bar;

    @javax.persistence.Converter
    public static class Converter implements AttributeConverter<FooBarType, String> {
        @Override
        public String convertToDatabaseColumn(FooBarType t) {
            return t.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public FooBarType convertToEntityAttribute(String s) {
            for (FooBarType value : FooBarType.values()) {
                if (value.name().equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }

            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value for enum: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

Entity:

```
@Table
public class FooBar {
    @EmbeddedId
    public PrimaryKey compositeKey;

    @Column(name = "value")
    public int value;

    @Embeddable
    public static class PrimaryKey implements Serializable {
        @Column(name = "id")
        public String id;

        @Column(name = "fooBarType")
        @Convert(converter = FooBarType.Converter.class)
        public FooBarType fooBarType;
    }
}
```

And my repository:

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends Repository<FooBar, FooBar.PrimaryKey> {
    FooBar getByCompositeKey(FooBar.PrimaryKey compositeKey);
}
```

Comment: Issue created in hibernate's JIRA. Affects 4.3.11.Final and 5.1.0.Final. 
Link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10594

Answer (score 0):

You should try enumerated like that:

```
@Id
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "foobar")
public FooBarType fooBarType;
```

And you repository:

```
public interface FooBarRepository extends Repository<FooBar, FooBar.PrimaryKey> {
    FooBar getByIdAndFooBarType(String id, FooBarType foobar);
}
```

Comment: If it's enumerated using the @Enumerated annotation, the conversion back from db to entity will fail if the case is incorrect with a different exception.

I'm trying to make a case-insensitive converter here.

Comment: Could you add exception to your post?

Comment: No problem. The expected exception for @Enumerated is added.